# 500 Error on JSP

Tags: jsp, http, tomcat, web-applications

I have created a web application using JSP Page, however it is throwing the below error.

Workflow: Index.jsp=> login.jsp=>calltomethods which are defined in the JAVA file.

**Index.jsp:**

```
<html>    
<body>

<form action="login.jsp">    

<table>    
<tr>
    <td> System: <input type="text" name="cmsname"/> </td>
</tr>    
<tr>
    <td> User Name: <input type="text" name="username"/> </td>
</tr>    
<tr>
    <td> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </td>
</tr>    
</table>

<input type = "submit" value = "Login">    
</form>

<form action="download.jsp">    
<input type = "submit" value = "Donwload File">    
</form>

</body>
```

**login.jsp**

```
<%@ page import = "com.aksl.internal.java.*" %>
<%@ page import = "javax.servlet.http.*" %>
<%@ page import = "java.io.IOException" %>

<html>
<body>

<%     
    String cmsname = request.getParameter("cmsname");
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    InitComCms initcmslogin = new InitComCms(); 
        initcmslogin.setCMS(cmsname);
        initcmslogin.setUserId(username);
        initcmslogin.setPassword(password);
        initcmslogin.callsToMethods();
%>

alert("User is logged in");

</body>    
</html>
```

**InitComCms.java**

this file has all the logic for login into the system and getting the details. This code will also write all the details to excel file as well on the local drive.

**Error:**

```
Nov 24, 2016 12:34:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/UserList41] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /login.jsp at line 13

10:     String cmsname = request.getParameter("cmsname");
11:     String username = request.getParameter("username");
12:     String password = request.getParameter("password");
13:     InitComCms initcmslogin = new InitComCms(); 
14:         initcmslogin.setCMS(cmsname);
15:         initcmslogin.setUserId(username);
16:         initcmslogin.setPassword(password);


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:126)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

By the way, I am a new bee in java. Below is the line no:13 from login.jsp file.

```
InitComCms initcmslogin = new InitComCms();
```

Please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: Class not found exception org.apache.poi
includes this class in your project

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `poi-VERSION.jar` from your classpath. Choose the proper version for your code and add it to the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your webapp.

Comment: Hi Jozef, Thank you for looking into this. I have already added the POI jar files in the lib folder. poi-3.10.1-20140818.jar 
poi-excelant-3.10.1-20140818.jar 
poi-ooxml-3.10.1-20140818.jar 
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10.1-20140818.jar 
poi-scratchpad-3.10.1-20140818.jar 
These are files what I have added, do I have to replace them with other versions of these files? If so then how can I identify the correct version which is needed? Thanks.

Comment: Hi All, can anyone help me with this please?